# Angular multi-line list click anywhere to navigate

Tags: html, angular

So this might be simple but I'm having a hard time making a list with two rows of data that allows the user to click anywhere on the entire list item to navigate. I currently have this:

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <h3 matSubheader>Recent</h3>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let book of recentBooks$ | async">
      <a matLine routerLink="/book/{{book.id}}"><strong>{{book.title}}</strong></a>
      <p matLine>{{book.description}}</p>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

This mostly works but clicking the line with the `book.description` doesn't navigate. I've tried using the `a` outside like so:

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <h3 matSubheader>Recent</h3>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let book of recentBooks$ | async">
    <a routerLink="/book/{{book.id}}">
      <p matLine><strong>{{book.title}}</strong></p>
      <p matLine>{{book.description}}</p>
    </a>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

But then the list items don't display correctly. I tried adding the `routerLink` property to both lines and that works but I don't think it's the correct way.

Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add `routerLink="/book/{{book.id}}"` in `mat-list-item` tag 
and remove **anchor** tag

this might work

Comment: Thanks! That works better than the answer I came up with. Didn't realize `book` would already be accessible in the same line as the for loop declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code it's work for me

````
<h3 matSubheader>Recent</h3>
<mat-list-item>
 <a [routerLink]="['/book',book.id]">
   <p matLine><strong>book</strong></p>
   <p matLine>This is a book</p>
 </a>
</mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. Moved made line with `*ngFor` just a `div`, then put the `mat-list-item` inside with the `routerLink`:

```
<mat-nav-list>
  <h3 matSubheader>Recent</h3>
  <div *ngFor="let book of recentBooks$ | async">
    <a mat-list-item routerLink="/book/{{book.id}}">
      <p matLine><strong>{{book.title}}</strong></p>
      <p matLine>{{book.description}}</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</mat-nav-list>
```

I don't know if there's any negatives to not having the immediate children of a `mat-nav-list` be `mat-list-item's` but it seems to look ok.